# TCPDF - remove empty gap when header is hidden

Tags: php, tcpdf

When I hide header with

```
$this->setPrintHeader(false);
```

it still leaves an empty gap (space) from the top. How to remove the gap so the body would appear from the beginning of page?

**EDIT1: this the prestashop function I use**

```
public function writePage()
{
    $this->SetTopMargin(-50);
    $this->SetHeaderMargin(-55);
    $this->setPrintHeader(false);
    $this->SetFooterMargin(21);
    $this->setMargins(10, 50, 10);
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 40);
    $this->AddPage();
    $this->writeHTML($this->content, true, false, true, false, '');      
}
```

**EDIT 2: this combination works for me**

```
$this->setPrintHeader(false);
$this->SetTopMargin(0);
$this->setMargins(10, 20, 10);  <- Now I can set margins as I want
```

Comment: Which version of TCPDF are your using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from not printing the header you also need to set margins to 0, so in this case:

`$this->SetTopMargin(0);`

Note that you can manipulate the margin of the header too with `$this->SetHeaderMargin();`

Edit: you can use negative values too.

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried negative values as well. See edit1.

Comment: It probably works, but after `$this->SetFooterMargin(21);` you are overriding these values with `$this->setMargins();` (the second param is `$topMargin`) - more here: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/tcpdf.php#L2561