# how to remove blank space for jspdf pdf in react js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, image-processing, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am new to react js and new to creating jspdf pdf. I am creating a pdf for download however I am getting blank space at the top of the pdf like so:

[image]

I want to remove this blank space that I am getting in the pdf. My html renders like this:

[image]

Here is the function to generate the pdf:

```
generatePDF = () => {
    window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
    

    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");

    doc.html(document.querySelector("#content"), {
      callback: function(pdf) {
        pdf.save("Coil_Details.pdf");
      }
    });
  };
```

Here is the function to download data:

```
getData = async () => {
    var ID = this.props.id;
    var promise = await this.getAuthorization();
    var proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    console.log("ID:" + ID);

    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: serverDetails.jwtTokenGenerationURL,
      params: {
        "jwt-token": jwtService.GetJWT()
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.statusText != "" && response.statusText != "OK") {
          return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
        } else {
          serverDetails.jwtResponse = response.data;

          //return response.data;
        }
      })

      .then(response => {
        var url = "api/observation/GetCoilImages";
        url += "?jwt=" + serverDetails.jwtResponse;
        url += "&ID=" + ID;
        axiosAPI
          // .get(url)
          .get(url)

          .then(response => {
            if (response.statusText != "" && response.statusText == "OK") {
              // window.open(response.data, '_blank');

              console.log("Response:" + response.data);
              console.log("Response1:" + response.data[0]);
              var code = [];
              for (var i in response.data) {
                code[i] = response.data[i];
                console.log("Code:" + code);
              }
              this.setState({ code });
            }

            this.setState({
              modal: !this.state.modal
            });
          });
      });
  };
```

Here is the html for the same:

```
return (
      <div>
        <i
          className="fa fa-list-alt"
          aria-hidden="true"
          // onClick={this.toggle}
          onClick={this.getData}
        ></i>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modal}
          toggle={this.toggle}
          className={this.props.className}
          size="lg"
          style={{ maxWidth: "700px", width: "100%" }}
        >
          <ModalHeader
            toggle={this.toggle}
            cssModule={{ "modal-title": "w-100 text-center" }}
          >
            Coil Details
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            {/* <Container fluid={true}>
              <Card className="card-profile shadow mt--100">
                <CardBody> */}
            <div id="content">
              <div>
                <Card className="card-profile shadow">
                  <center>
                    {/* <img src={this.props.url} width="100%" height="250px" /> */}
                    {/* <img src={code} width="100%" height="250px" /> */}
                    {/* {this.state.code.map(({ src }) => (
                      <img src={src} key={src} width="40%" height="50px" />
                    ))} */}
                    {this.state.code.map((imgSrc, index) => (
                      <img
                        src={imgSrc}
                        key={index}
                        width="100%"
                        height="250px"
                        style={{
                          border: "5px solid #000000",
                          margin: "3px 3px 3px 3px"
                        }}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </center>
                </Card>
              </div>
              <hr></hr>
              <br></br>

              <Row style={{ marginTop: "1rem", marginLeft: "1rem" }}>
                <Col lg="3" style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>Type</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="typeTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.type}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="3" style={{ marginTop: "1rem", marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>Coil ID</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="coilTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.id}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col lg="3" style={{ marginTop: "1rem", marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>View</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="viewTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.view}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <hr></hr>

              <Row style={{ marginLeft: "1rem" }}>
                <Col lg="3">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>Delivery No</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="deliveryTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.delivery}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="3" style={{ marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>Invoice No</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="invoiceTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.invoice}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col lg="3" style={{ marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>Wagon No</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="wagonTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.wagon}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <hr></hr>

              <Row style={{ marginLeft: "1rem" }}>
                <Col lg="3">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>Location</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="locationTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.location}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="3" style={{ marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>ICHP</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="ICHPTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.ICHP}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col lg="3" style={{ marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>Remarks</label>
                    <Input
                      type="textarea"
                      id="remarksTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.remarks}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row>
                <Col
                  lg="5"
                  style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
                >
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="dateTextField"
                      size="sm"
                      defaultValue={this.props.date}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>

            {/* </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Container> */}
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.generatePDF}>
              Download
            </Button>{" "}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why am I getting this blank space at the top and how to remove it. Please help

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774082/tcpdf-remove-empty-gap-when-header-is-hidden

Comment: how do I add SetTopMargin(0) in react??

Comment: and specifically in jspdf

Comment: i hope this answers your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012181/jspdf-add-margins-to-pdf-page

Comment: margins doesnt work here